# Unable to get Ormlite working after using Proguard

Tags: android, proguard, ormlite

I am using ormlite 4.24.

after building a release build using `shrinkResources true`
            `minifyEnabled true` my app fails with the following errors:

```
"java.lang.RuntimeException: java.sql.SQLException: SQL statement failed: CREATE TABLE `ac` (`A` VARCHAR , `B` VARCHAR , `C` VARCHAR..."
```

After trying options such as:

```
# OrmLite uses reflection
-keep class com.j256.**
-keepclassmembers class com.j256.** { *; }
-keep enum com.j256.**
-keepclassmembers enum com.j256.** { *; }
-keep interface com.j256.**
-keepclassmembers interface com.j256.** { *; }
```

I am still not able to use the release build.

I have tried using Ormlite ver. 5 including additional settings such as:

```
# OrmLite uses reflection
-keep class com.j256.**
-keepclassmembers class com.j256.** { *; }
-keep enum com.j256.**
-keepclassmembers enum com.j256.** { *; }
-keep interface com.j256.**
-keepclassmembers interface com.j256.** { *; }

# Keep the helper class and its constructor
-keep class * extends com.j256.ormlite.android.apptools.OrmLiteSqliteOpenHelper
-keepclassmembers class * extends com.j256.ormlite.android.apptools.OrmLiteSqliteOpenHelper {
  public <init>(android.content.Context);
}

# keep the classes and members of our entities or OrmLite will not work
-keep class com.myApp.activity.**
-keepclassmembers class com.myApp.activity.** {*;}

# Keep the annotations
-keepattributes Exceptions,InnerClasses,Signature,Deprecated,SourceFile,LineNumberTable,*Annotation*,EnclosingMethod

-libraryjars <java.home>/lib/rt.jar


# Keep all model classes that are used by OrmLite
# Also keep their field names and the constructor
-keep @com.j256.ormlite.table.DatabaseTable class * {
    @com.j256.ormlite.field.DatabaseField <fields>;
    @com.j256.ormlite.field.ForeignCollectionField <fields>;
    # Add the ormlite field annotations that your model uses here

    <init>();
}

-keepattributes Signature
-keep class com.myApp.activity.database.** { *; }

-keepclassmembers class classpath.** {
  public *;
}

-dontwarn org.slf4j.**
-dontwarn org.apache.log4j.**
-dontwarn org.apache.commons.logging.**
-dontwarn org.apache.commons.codec.binary.**
-dontwarn javax.persistence.**
-dontwarn javax.lang.**
-dontwarn javax.annotation.**
-dontwarn javax.tools.**
```

but I am still not able to to run my App. I currently getting the following errors:

```
"java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No fields have a DatabaseField annotation in class com.myApp.bean.p"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For OrmLite I use this config:

```
-keepattributes *Annotation*,Signature

-dontnote com.j256.ormlite.android.apptools.OrmLiteSqliteOpenHelper
-keepclassmembers class * extends com.j256.ormlite.android.apptools.OrmLiteSqliteOpenHelper {
    <init>(android.content.Context);
}

-dontnote com.j256.ormlite.field.DatabaseFieldConfig
-keepclassmembers class com.j256.ormlite.field.DatabaseFieldConfig {
    <fields>;
}

-dontnote com.j256.ormlite.dao.Dao
-keepclassmembers class * implements com.j256.ormlite.dao.Dao {
    <init>(**);
    <init>(**, java.lang.Class);
}

-dontnote com.j256.ormlite.android.AndroidLog
-keep class com.j256.ormlite.android.AndroidLog {
    <init>(java.lang.String);
}

-dontnote com.j256.ormlite.table.DatabaseTable
-keep @com.j256.ormlite.table.DatabaseTable class * {
    void set*(***);
    *** get*();
}

-dontnote com.j256.ormlite.field.DatabaseField
-keepclassmembers @interface com.j256.ormlite.field.DatabaseField {
    <methods>;
}

-dontnote com.j256.ormlite.field.ForeignCollectionField
-keepclassmembers @interface com.j256.ormlite.field.ForeignCollectionField {
    <methods>;
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    @com.j256.ormlite.field.DatabaseField <fields>;
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    @com.j256.ormlite.field.ForeignCollectionField <fields>;
}

-dontnote org.joda.time.DateTime
-keep,allowobfuscation class org.joda.time.DateTime
-keepclassmembers class org.joda.time.DateTime {
    <init>(long);
    long getMillis();
}
```

That should be all that's necessary.